# Notifications about any window's movements/resizing

Tags: java, jna

How to get notifications about new location or size of a window whose handler I have access to (any window, so it can be Firefox, Windows Explorer, Skype, etc.)? Only hooks? :/ The problem with them is that there are only examples with WH_KEYBOARD_LL and WH_MOUSE_LL as arguments of SetWindowsHookEx function. Besides them nothing works as regards JNA. Any ideas how to deal with it? Maybe no hooks, but other functions?

Answer (score 0):

Because the other "higher-level" hooks require that the hook code reside in a DLL, JNA can't provide those hooks.